# How to copy primitive type memory in Java?

Tags: java, memory, types, copy, primitive

I have two chars = 4 bytes, that representing integer value (geted from stream).

How can I copy these into a primitive int variable?

Comment: Can you post the code you currently have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are better off reading 4 bytes as an `int` from the start.  However to turn two char into an int you can use

```
char ch1, ch2;
int i = (ch1 << 16) + ch2; // or ch2 << 16 + ch1
```

You need to know whether the order is little or big endian.

Comment: @Vineet, good point. `+` has high precedence than `<<` which is higher than `|` which is why Mat's answer doesn't need brackets. http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Comment: It's a some kind of manual copying. Do java have some memcpy function like C++ does?

Comment: If you want to do this sort of thing you can use direct ByteBuffers, which is also the most efficient way of reading data from a stream. However if you already have read two `char` this is the simplest.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one possible way of doing it:

```
char a = 0x00FF;
char b = 0x0F0F;
int  i = b << 16 | a;
```

BUT: you'll have to worry about endianness, and about the fact that `int` is signed.